# How to use BeyondCompare from git mergetool in cygwin?

Tags: git, merge, cygwin, beyondcompare, mergetool

How to use BeyondCompare from "git mergetool" in cygwin?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple answer.

```
#! /bin/sh
LOCAL=`cygpath -wa $1`
REMOTE=`cygpath -wa $2`
BASE=`cygpath -wa $3`
MERGED=`cygpath -wa $4`
/cygdrive/c/BeyondCompare3/BComp.exe $LOCAL $THEIRS $BASE $MERGED
```

Or as in your git config.

```
[mergetool "mergetool"]
    cmd = /cygdrive/c/BeyondCompare3/BComp.exe `cygpath -wa "$LOCAL"` `cygpath -wa "$REMOTE"` `cygpath -wa "$BASE"` `cygpath -wa "$MERGED"`
```

I use cygpath (which comes with cygwin) to convert the paths. The `-w` flag converts from cygwin format (starting with /cygdrive/c) to windows format (starting with c:). The `-a` flag uses absolute filenames.

Note: I don't have a Pro BeyondCompare license, so I can't test merge properly, but it is correctly opening the first two files.

Answer (score 2):

I've found some scripts to convert cygwin paths (robustly, it seems) and launch BC3:
http://gist.github.com/564573

Comment: I'm rather uncertain about how the paths are cleaned up, though. Can this be simpler? I'd love to do this purely by configuring git and not using a shell script.